# How to embed a link (or preview) of the "About Me" MySite of a certain user into a page in SharePoint 2013

Tags: my-site, url

In a SharePoint 2013 publishing page, I want to insert contact information for technical support for the SharePoint portal.

I wonder how I can insert a link (or even preview) to my MySite which then gives other users the possibility to see my e-mail address, click on it to send me a message and see my photo.

One problem:
if I use "About me" to navigate to my MySite, the URL looks like that:
`http://portalname/my/Person.aspx`

So if I would paste that link, it would (I assume) lead every user to his own MySite, but not to mine...

I found out that http://portalname/my/personal/username/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/default.aspx leads to the "My Content" page, but I want to link to the "About Me" page with the contact information (phone, etc.)